# Sequence of a product of Bernoulli random variables is a Markov Chain?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Suppose we have a sequence of random variables $X_n$ defined as $X_n = \prod_{i=0}^n Z_i $ where $Z_i$ for i=0,1,2,3... is a sequence of i.i.d variables with the Bernoulli distribution with parameter p. I wanted to ask if $X_n$ is a Markov chain? I had concerns over the fact that knowing if one of the $X_n = 0$ would break the required independence?

Comment: You know the precise definition of a Markov chain, I suppose?  Where did you get stuck in trying to verify it?

Comment: So I know we are trying to show that $X_n+1$ conditioned on $X_0,...X_n$ is just equal to $X_n+1$ conditioned on $X_n$. What was I thinking that if one of the $X_0,,...X_n-1$ were $0$ then don't we know that $X_n+1$ is going to be 0? hence it isn't Markov? But at the same time, I was able to show it was Markov when not considering the values of 0,1 i.e just considering $X_0 = i_0, ... X_n = i_n$

Comment: It's true that if any of the $X_0, \dots, X_{n-1}$ are zero, then $X_{n+1}$ is zero.  Why do you think this is a problem?  It means, for instance, that the event $\{X_0 = 0, \dots, X_{n+1}=1\}$ has probability zero, and so you don't need to consider conditioning on it.

Comment: Also, please be more precise with your definition.  There is no such thing as "a random variable conditioned on other random variables".  The definition of a Markov chain involves certain *conditional probabilities*.

Comment: I just thought that it would mean there is dependence between the past and the future given the present meaning that it's no longer Markov

Comment: That's not the definition of the Markov property.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add given the present

Comment: Right.  And it's absolutely true for this process that the past and future are *conditionally* independent given the present.  If you know the value of $X_n$, then knowing the values of $X_0, \dots, X_{n-1}$ doesn't give you any useful *additional* information about $X_{n+1}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assume $X_0=0$. For all $n\geqslant0$ we have $$X_{n+1} = Z_{n+1}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} Z_i = Z_{n+1}X_n.$$
Since $X_n$ is $\sigma(X_n)$-measurable and $Z_{n+1}$ is indepenent of $\{X_i: 1\leqslant i\leqslant n\}$, it follows that for any continuous bounded $f:\{0,1\}\to\mathbb R$,
$$
\mathbb E[f(X_{n+1})\mid\mathcal F_n] = \mathbb E[f(Z_{n+1}X_n)\mid\mathcal F_n] = \mathbb E[f(Z_{n+1}X_n)\mid X_n],
$$
so that $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov process. Indeed, the $n$-step transition matrix is given by
$$
P^n = \begin{pmatrix}p^n&1-p^n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$